# Why is the 'Track To' constraint not working?

Tags: constraints

When I use the *Track To* constraint, my object snaps out of the original position and doesn’t track on the direction I want it to. How can I fix this?

---

before adding the tract to constraint, the body of the link rod is connected to the fuselage.[image]

---

after adding the tract to constraint, the body of the link rod is disconnects from the fuselage to a different position.[image]

Comment: Play with the "To" and "Up" axes, what works most of the time for me is "To" : "-Z" and "Up" : "Y"

Comment: Before doing that, it can be useful to display the local axis of your objects. In Object Properties, under Viewport Display, tick Axis.

Comment: Hi. I suggest adding some before/after images to your post to illustrate your point.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably long since answered, but (using Blender 3.0), the issue for me was setting the "Track Axis" properly in the bone constraint, as well as setting the Head/Tail tracking option to the one you want.